# .Net/SQL Server/Powershell - Extract keyword/value from Word Doc

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell

Using .Net, we need to search to through word document and extra required values  for the keywords searched. See example below, Please help as im new to .Net

Source Doc (Word document has nearly 300 pages which needs to be searched through):

```
"Margin" means:
(a) in relation to any Facility A Loan [2% ] per cent. per annum;
(b) in relation to any Facility B Loan [ 5% ] per cent. per annum;
(c) in relation to any Facility C Loan [ 10% ] per cent. per annum;

Search for following in doc:
Facility A Loan (under Margins section)
Facility B Loan (under Margins section)
Facility C Loan (under Margins section)

Output Required (values within bracket to be extracted):
2%
5%
10%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things -

1. Parse the Document-

To accomplish this use this link as a reference - [C#: How to (parse the text content)/ read from Microsoft Word Document doc](http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-parse-the-text-content-from-microsoft-word-document/)

2. Capture the text

Use following regular expression -

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Refer this site for more information - [Regular Expression in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/955025/regular-expression-in-C-Sharp/)